# How to have a called controller on every page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, hidden

I want to have a controller to do some initial settings and fetch some basic data in all of my application pages (written with PHP and CodeIgniter). As I'm new in CI, please help me to do it.
Some of my goals to have such controller:

1. Setup submenus (regardless of the current page)
2. Check user login status.

**Notice:**

I don't have any problem on creating and working with general Controllers in CI. What I need is something like a hidden controller that does not any need to URI segments to run, and it is not the CI default controller too.

Comment: You need to create helper in codeigniter.

Comment: @NikhilVaghla I did some searchs and I think the answer is here : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html. What's you idea?

Comment: Instead of core classes I would suggest [creating libraries](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) instead. They are perfectly suited for code that can be used in many different controllers. Create core classes when you want to change how the Codeigniter framework is structured.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a base controller and and extend that base controller in every other controllers instead of `CI_Controller`. Your base controller will extend `CI_Controller`. You can add your required checks in the constructor of the base controller and do stuffs according to that. So every time you call a controller your checks will be done. But you have autoload the base controller. I hope this helps you.